# Change axios get url as per value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is my first react app and I am trying to fetch API using axios.

The URL can be changed based on a value.

My code is

```
fetchURL(page,checked) {
  if(checked)
  {
     const apiUrl = 'firstApiURL'
  }
  else {
     const apiUrl = 'secondApiURL';
  }
   axios.get(apiUrl)......
}
```

It says apiUrl is undefined.

I thought it would be easy to change the API url based on another variable.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way for Conditional Variable Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926853/best-way-for-conditional-variable-assignment)

Comment: I knew about scope block but I didn't had that in mind. Just started learning ReactJS. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants are scoped to the block they are declared in (between the `{` and the `}` associated with the `if` and the `else` respectively and are not accessible outside that scope.

Define a *variable* outside the block and use that instead.

```
fetchURL(page,checked) {
  let apiUrl;
  if(checked)
  {
    apiUrl = 'firstApiURL'
  }
  else {
    apiUrl = 'secondApiURL';
  }
   axios.get(apiUrl)......
}
```

You can then use a default value instead of an `else`.

```
fetchURL(page,checked) {
  let apiUrl = 'secondApiURL';
  if(checked)
  {
    apiUrl = 'firstApiURL'
  }
  axios.get(apiUrl)......
}
```

Or to simplify further and still use `const`

```
fetchURL(page, checked) {
  const apiUrl = checked ? 'firstApiURL' : 'secondApiURL';
  axios.get(apiUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code the `const` are defined in the block scope of `{}` so they are undefined outside.

Use `let` so you can assign to it, and declare it outside the `if`/`else`

```js
let apiUrl;
if (checked) {
  apiUrl = 'firstApiURL'
} else {
  apiUrl = 'secondApiURL';
}
axios.get(apiUrl)......
}
```

for more info on block statements and scope read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/block

Answer (score 1):

`const` key word create constant which exists only in blocks in which they were created (`let` and `const` words create block-scope variables).

`if() { }` and `else { }` are blocks for our created `apiUrl`, and ``apiUrl do not exist outside them.

You could write `let` variable outside `if` and `else` and then write to it some value. For example:

```js
fetchURL(page,checked) {
  let apiUrl;
  if(checked)
  {
     apiUrl = 'firstApiURL'
  }
  else {
     apiUrl = 'secondApiURL';
  }
   axios.get(apiUrl)......
}
```